# Spring 1-Many Rest Controller ForeignKey NULL

Tags: spring, rest

I have a 1-M relation between Patient and Consult Entities defined below:

### Patient:

```
@Entity
@Table(
        name = "Patient",
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
                name="patient_number_unique",
                columnNames="patientNumber"
        )
)

public class Patient {
    
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator( 
            name="patient_sequence",
            sequenceName="patient_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
            
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "patient_seqeunce"
    
    )
    private Long patientId;
    
    @Column(name = "patientNumber",
            nullable = false
    )
    private String patientNumber;
    
    private String patientName;
    private String medicalAid;
    private String medicalAidNumber;
    
    // Define 1-Many Relation Patient can come for many consults.
    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "patient_id",
            referencedColumnName = "patientId"
    )
    private List<Consult> consults;// Patient can  have many List of Consults
    
}
```

### Consult:

```
@Entity
@Table(
        name = "Consult"
      )

public class Consult {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "consult_sequence",
            sequenceName = "consult_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
            
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "consult_sequence"
    )
    private Long consultId;
       
    private String consultDate;
    private String reservationNumber;
```

I need help with the restcontroller method to add a consult for a patient.

```
@PostMapping("/patient/{patient_id}/consult") //Add a consult
```

ConsultController I have:

```
 @RequestMapping(value= "/patient/{patientId}/consult", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    public Consult addConsult(@PathVariable(value="patientId") Long patientId, @RequestBody Consult consult){
        return consultService.addConsult(consult);
        }
```

I don't know how to pass patientId to update consult. Consult table is updated but patientId is NULL

Comment: What is wrong with the current restcontroller? Please elaborate what exactly is your issue.

Comment: I've added more detail to original post...@NicoVanBelle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know how to pass patientId to update consult. Consult table is updated but patientId is NULL

You are using a "unidirectional" one-to-many annotation so what you have to do is to load the `Patient` object from database (given its `patientId`) and then add to its `consults` list the `consult` object.

e.g. Provided you have a `PatientService` to deal with CRUD operations for the `Patient` entity the following code should work:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/patient/{patientId}/consult", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public Consult addConsult(@PathVariable(value="patientId") Long patientId, @RequestBody Consult consult){
    Patient patient = patientService.getPatient(patientId); //load patient entity from DB via its id, you should have a method doing this
    patient.getConsults().add(consult); //list should not be null here, make sure you initialize it somewhere prior reaching this line
    patientService.save(patient);
}
```

Comment: patientId is implicit as it's defined in Patient Entity as @OneToMany @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="patientId"). So no setter (no setPatientId)?

Comment: It would be helpful to edit your question and post your Patient and Consult classes. In my opinion you should also have a setter of patient in Consult class.

Comment: added Patient and Consult classes

Comment: Updated my answer, you can also see here for one-to-many relationships: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/